# How to stop a php script after N seconds using set_time_limit?

Tags: php

I have that simplest possible script:

```
 <?php
if( ini_get('safe_mode') ){
  echo "safe mode !";
}else{
   echo "NOT safe mode !";
}

set_time_limit(3);

for ($i=0;$i<30;$i++) {
    sleep(1);
    echo $i;
}
```

I have as output
Not safe mode
0123456....

Why does my script does not stop after 3 seconds ?

(I run it in SSH console)

Comment: you need to call the `die()` function . this will kill your php script, remember that `die()` kills the script at that point.

Comment: yes I know I can die or exit a script anytime. I want it to be died after some N seconds (some timeout !)

Comment: try ini_set('max_execution_time', 3);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time spent `sleep`ing doesn't count towards script execution time. From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

> The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows where the measured time is real.

Answer (score 0):

AS @iainn said in his answer, `set_time_limit()` only counts the actual processing time the PHP script does. So when sleeping or waiting for other processes, it won't be counted towards the limit. (Except for on Windows.)

However, to answer the question in your title:
In order to stop it after 3 seconds of "real time", simply create a variable that contains the starting time (in ms), and then check this inside the loop. Preferably before the sleep. Then, if it's > 3000 ms just `break` from the loop. ;)

Comment: I had this idea too, but it's not a universal solution, because sometimes we have to call a library function which we can't change. For example, I have a problem with Laravel's Excel library, sometimes file is too large and the import fails because of timing, but I can't really alter anything in this function